# Pseudospectral Optimal Control

Tags: numerical-methods, optimal-control

I want to implement a pseudospectral methods to solve (nonlinear) Optimal Control Problems, for instance

$$J(u)=\int_0^T L(x(t),u(t),t) dt $$

s.t

$$x(t)'=a(x(t),u(t),t)$$
$$x(0)=t_b, x(T)=t_e$$

The approches I found so far, are only give a sketch how to do it. What I need is a clear algorithmn how to approch this. I am not sure If I  should take an iterative Scheme like choosing $u_0(t)$ and then solve the Integral and ODE seperatly, which leads to an nonlinear OP, or should I first build the Hamiliton? I would be thankful for Tipps and reference to some papers which make it clear for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may check papers by A.Rao, e.g., [this one](http://www.anilvrao.com/Publications/JournalPublications/unifiedFramework.pdf) or an [introductory tutorial](http://www.matthewpeterkelly.com/research/MattKelly__Transcription_Methods_for_Trajectory_Optimization.pdf) by M. Kelly.

In general, before starting you should first decide whether you wish to implement a direct or an indirect optimal control method. The latter will involve writing down the system of $2n$ Hamiltonian equations and solving it numerically while the former attempts to find an optimal solution by direct minimization of $J(u)$. The choice will depend on the problem at hand: set of constraints, admissible controls etc.